# Is it possible to do custom imports with Webpack like it is with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, browserify, amd

So in my projects I tend to have a lot of custom scripts, as well as components etc.

I really don't like this pattern of importing things:

```
import Navigation from '../../Navigation/Navigation.js

/* or */

import Navigation from 'src/universal/components/Navigation/Navigation.js'
```

Is it possible to declare an entry point via Webpack like it is with Browserify? I am making the switch now and will sorely miss this functionality if it's not possible

With Browserify, declaring custom imports is as easy as including this in your `package.json`:

```
"browser": {
  "navigation": "src/universal/components/Navigation/Navigation"
}
```

Then, to import anywhere, it's as simple as:

```
import Navigation from 'navigation'
```

**How does one do this via Webpack?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try use [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias)

> [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) - Replace modules by other modules or paths.

*`webpack.config.js`*

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
     navigation: 'src/universal/components/Navigation/Navigation'
  }
}
```